# Eine Frau kann "zierlich" sein. Wie nennt man einen ebensolchen Mann?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjective

Für eine kleine Frau haben wir das Attribut *"[zierlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zierlich)"*, das auf nette Art beschreibt, dass sie zwar klein, aber doch *"fein gestaltet und graziös"* ist.

Kann man einen Mann auch *"zierlich"* nennen, ohne ihn dabei eventuell zu beleidigen? Gibt es vielleicht einen anderen, besser geeigneten Ausdruck?

Comment: Suchst du eine Bezeichnung für kleine, schlanke Männer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für Männer wie für Frauen kommt mir das Wort **feingliedrig** / **feingliederig** in den Sinn.

Es hat nicht die Bedeutung niedlich, die bei zierlich mitschwingen kann. Stattdessen sehe ich als Hauptbedeutungsfelder grazil und zerbrechlich, eben bedingt durch die Körperproportionen langer Gliedmaßen.
Es wird häufig auf Hände, aber auch auf wachsende, verästelte Strukturen (z.B. Bäume) und mechanische Bauteile (Ketten, Teile der Feinmechanik) angewandt.
Der Duden führt es als Synonym zu fragil. Die meisten auf Männer bezogenen Beispiele im DWDS betonen weiblichen Körperbau.

Beispiele (aus dem DWDS):

> Die Zeit, 10.07.2012
>
> Heinz Ratjen wurde bei seiner Geburt als Tochter eingetragen und
>   musste fortan Mädchenkleider tragen. Da er sehr feingliedrig war, fiel
>   das lange nicht auf. Erst als er den Hochsprung-Weltrekord 1938 auf
>   1,70 Meter verbesserte, provozierte er seine Entdeckung.

und

> Die Zeit, 06.07.2012
>
> Gerade das deutsche Team bekommt das zu spüren –
>   eben wegen des Stilwechsels, der unter Trainer Klinsmann begann. Statt
>   „unflexibler Hypermaskulinitäten“ wie Oliver Kahn oder Jürgen Kohler
>   kommen zunehmend junge Spieler mit „eher feingliedrigem“ Körperbau zum
>   Einsatz, zarte, jungenhafte „Metrosexuelle“, die elegant und
>   leichtfüßig spielen. Eben das, die „Schönheit“ des deutschen Spiels
>   aber beschwört auch den Verdacht der „Unmännlichkeit“ herauf –
>   besonders dann, wenn der Erfolg ausbleibt:

und

> Glaser, Curt, Japanisches Theater, in: ders., Japanisches Theater,
>   Berlin-Lankwitz: Würfel-Verl. 1930, S. 11-19, S. 4
>
> In der Frühzeit waren es eigene Schauspieler, die dafür ausgebildet,
>   im allgemeinen nur Frauenrollen darstellten. Sie werden auch von
>   Meistern wie Shunshô und Bunchô als feingliedrige, zartgesichtige
>   Wesen geschildert. Um die Mitte des XVIII.

Answer (score 11):

Eine Frau kann zierlich und grazil sein. Ein Mann ist klein und schmächtig.

Ein positiv besetztes Adjektiv gibt es für Männer in diesem Fall (noch) nicht. Dies hängt mit der Idealvorstellung zusammen, die sich über die Jahrtausende geprägt hat:

Frauen sind klein, zierlich und schützenswert. Männer sind groß, muskulös und beschützend.

Eine große kräftige Frau positiv und in prägnanter Weise zu beschreiben, wird genauso schwerfallen. *Walküre* oder *Amazone* kommt sogleich in den Sinn. Beide Wörter können durchaus auch negativ besetzt sein.

Also rate ich zu ausschmückenderen Beschreibungen, wie „klein und drahtig“ und Ähnliches, was schon in den anderen Antworten erwähnt wurde.

Comment: Eine große, kräftige Frau wird - oder wurde zumindest - gerne auch als *stattlich* beschrieben. *Schmächtig* ist zwar auch leicht negativ, aber immerhin noch deutlich milder als die anderen Formen.

Answer (score 5):

Ein **schlaksiger** Mann ist schlank, aber gleichzeitig wird auch eine gewisse, unproportionale Länge mit dem Wort transportiert, und ein unbeholfener Bewegungsablauf, was beim 'zierlich' nicht der Fall wäre.

> Littbarski war ein eher zierlicher Stürmer

ist aber keineswegs abwertend (auch wenn es vielleicht nicht ganz stimmt – die Oberschenkel habe ich jetzt nicht vor Augen). Bei einem Balletttänzer käme dies aber in Betracht, auch bei Musikern, Künstlern und allen anderen Berufen, bei denen schiere Kraft nicht so wichtig ist wie bei Möbelpackern und Hollywoodstars.

Answer (score 4):

First off: +1 for an awesome question :)

I'm hoping for a lot of answers, because right away (with only two so far) there appear very different views on what visuals and descriptions fit together here... :)

**I vote for:**

- *drahtig* – someone who is "sportlich" but not overly muscular and not very tall (free climbing or similar sports), also an implied nimbleness
- *zäh* – in some areas of Germany, this would convey the idea pretty well
- *durchtrainiert* – very similar to "drahtig", maybe a bit more general
- *schlank* – "zierlich" implies "schlank", but not the other way round
- *stramm* – quite unusual, but why not? I'd be careful, though - to me, it somehow sounds not like a neutral assessment of body shape but loaded with overtones...
- gelenkig –  large overlap with "zierlich", but emphasis is on movement, not stature

**the following fit, kind of, but only describe parts of "zierlich":**

- *fit* – too vague, no indication of actual size or width :)
- *sportlich*, *sportiv* – same as "fit"*
- *gut gebaut* – *very* dependent on taste, I guess most people associate tall, right?
- *muskulös* – no indication of height

**the following don't work for me:**

- *athletisch* – too large
- *smart* – I associate this with clothing and grooming
- *kraftvoll*, *kraftstotzend* – like "muskulös", maybe tending to tall
- *robust* – this is the exact opposite of "zierlich"
- *markig* – similar to "robust", someone who's "markig" will likely punch you if you suggest he's "kind of zierlich"

My point: this appears to be heavily dependent who you're talking to - e.g. if Em1 described someone to me, I'd obviously form an entirely different picture in my mind, and vice versa. :)

*edited to incorporate Em1's correction

Comment: Ok, if I ever have to describe someone to you I will send you pictures ;p I agree to your description in general. I just mentioned some alternatives which are possible. Though, as I said there is no equivalent word to *zierlich*.

Comment: lol, gute Idee! :)

Comment: Durchtrainiert, drahtig, muskulös und gut gebaut sind für mich so ziemlich das Gegenteil von zierlich.

Answer (score 1):

Einfach nur "schlank" oder "drahtig" wäre passend, vielleicht auch "athletisch"

Comment: hmmm... "drahtiger Sitzriese"?

Answer (score 1):

Grundsätzlich stimme ich [@Feroc](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/eine-frau-kann-zierlich-sein-wie-nennt-man-einen-ebensolchen-mann/3951#3951) zu.

Wenn ich dich richtig verstehe, möchtest du kleine Männer beschreiben.

*Athletisch* beschreibt imho große Menschen. Wenn ich das Wort höre, habe ich automatisch einen Läufer, Springer, … im Hinterkopf (Stichwort Leichtathletik) und da sind lange Beine von Vorteil.

*Drahtig* passt auch, wobei das in meinem Verständnis ebenfalls eher einen größeren Mann bezeichnet. Man stellt sich einfach mal einen Draht vor, dieser ist wesentlich länger als dick, nicht wahr?

Daher schließe ich diese beiden Wörter als erste Wahl aus, obwohl ich sie durchaus als Alternative wählen würde.

*Schlank* bedeutet indirekt auch *groß*, setzt dies aber nicht voraus. Finde ich daher auch eine gute Wortwahl, hat aber auf der anderen Seite teils auch eine leicht negative Bedeutung. Wird eine Person als *schlank* bezeichnet, heißt das indirekt, dass diese Person wenig Muskelmasse aufweist, und der durchschnittliche mitteleuropäische Mensch findet daher (zu) schlanke Menschen weniger anmutig oder graziös.

Möchtest du jetzt also kleine Männer bezeichnen, empfehle ich diese Worte:

- *durchtrainiert*
- *fit*
- *sportlich*

Dies sind alles Begriffe, die nicht indirekt eine gewisse Körpergröße andeuten.

Mir fällt kein Begriff ein, der ein wirklich passendes Gegenstück zu *zierlich* ist. Wörter, mit denen man kleine Menschen beschreiben kann, wären *untersetzt*, *gedrungen*, *kompakt* und evtl. *stämmig*. Aber dies bezeichnet alles eher dicklich und definitiv nicht anmutig oder zierlich.

Noch eine Handvoll Ideen, die in meinem Verständnis keine Größenangabe beinhalten oder kleine Menschen bezeichnen und mit dem *mitteleuropäischen Schönheitsideal* kooperieren:

- sportiv
- gut gebaut
- stramm
- smart (weniger auf klug bezogen)
- muskulös
- kraftvoll
- robust
- kraftstrotzend
- gelenkig (=> oft klein und kräftig, man denke an Artisten im Zirkus)
- markig

Comment: Bei _drahtig_ denke ich unwillkürlich an was kleines, vielleicht weil unsere Nachbarn mal einen Drahthaardackel hatten.

Comment: @hmundt Ich kenne diese Dackelsorte zwar nicht, aber der Name lässt mich glauben, dass Draht sich nicht auf die Größe der eh schon kleinen Dackel bezieht, sondern sein Fell bezeichnet. Wie auch immer *Drahthaar* aussieht ;p

Comment: @hmundt: mit *drahtig* ist es vielleicht ähnlich wie mit *zierlich*, das ja im Grunde auch keine Größenangabe enthält.

Comment: @Takkat: Aber "zierlich" heißt doch auf jeden Fall "eher klein", oder?

Comment: @Mac: ja klar, **klein** und fein... nur von der Etymologie nicht - das wäre ja vielleicht bei *"drahtig"* oder einem noch zu findenden Adjektiv auch so.

Comment: @Takkat: Das ist aber ohnehin nicht sooo häufig der Fall, dass ein direkter etymologischer Bezug besteht... (wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe und Du damit ausdrückliches Vorkommen von "groß", "klein" oder Derivaten davon meinst)

Comment: @Em1: Du hast natürlich recht, ein Drahthaardackel ist kein drahtiger Haardackel sondern ein drahthaariger Dackel :)